# Symfony 3: http_method_override=true prevents form validation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Bug [#23254](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/23254) was fixed in Symfony 3.3.3. Its effect is to actually add the hidden `_method` to the form input fields when the original form method is not POST or GET. `_method` contains the original form method so that it can be recovered when the form is submitted.

But I have a subform containing a non POST method (`setMethod('PUT')` to be precise). Therefore, it adds that `_method` to its parameters and that `_method` overrides the POST method from the parent form.

As a form is validated only if the request method matches the form method, changing the request method fails to validate the parent form.

Here is a trimmed down sample code:

```
class PartnerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('partnerRoles', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => PartnerRoleType::class,
            ));
    }
}

class PartnerRoleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('PUT')
        ;
    }
}
```

Since upgrading to Symfony 3.3.5, the `PartnerType` form isn't validated any more as `$request->method()` returns "PUT" due to the `_method` field added by `ParterRoleType` and the `PartnerType` form is expecting a "POST" method.

I fixed it by configuring `http_method_override` to false to keep the POST method but it breaks forms that really use PUT. With those forms, the method is replaced by POST in the web page but `_method` isn't processed to get back to the real PUT when the form is submitted.

I would expect the `_method` input field not to be added if the form is part of a parent form. Is this a Symfony bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in Symfony. A child form should never add its hidden `_method` when its `form_rest()` is called.

Symfony starting with versions 2.7.30, 2.8.23, 3.2.10 and 3.3.3 are affected (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/23254).

A [patch](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/23649) is being processed at the time of writing.